# Manejo de errores en Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, excepciones

Tengo este código para un *token*, generado con `JWT`, luego lo retorno a la aplicación si el usuario accedió correctamente.

```
var token = $localStorage.token;
var base64Url = token.split('.')[1];
var base64 = base64Url.replace('-', '+').replace('_', '/');
var tokenObj = JSON.parse(atob(base64));
```

luego valido que el *token* tenga el siguiente *claim* `webUserId`

```
if(tokenObj.webUserId){...}
```

Si reemplazo el valor del *token* en el *localstorage*, espero que salga un error porque no está bien construido, pero en este punto me sale una excepción:

```
var tokenObj = JSON.parse(atob(base64));
```

me sale en Angular un `$exceptionHandler` en la consola de *debug*.

¿Cómo puedo controlar este error para que no salga la excepción de angular?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para evitar el error puedes capturar la excepción con un bloque `try...catch`

```
var tokenObj;
try {
    tokenObj = JSON.parse(atob(base64));
}
catch(e) {
    logMyErrors(e);
}
```

La variable `tokenObj` no estoy seguro de que la tengas que declarar fuera, supongo que dependerá de si tienes `"use strict";` pero por si acaso no está mal ahí

También podrías comprobar si tienes algo almacenado en **localstorage** antes de intentar convertirlo como **JSON**

**Actualización:**  el control de excepciones que comenta Leandro está bien pero, en este caso, quizás sea más conveniente controlar el error localmente para que continúe el flujo de ejecución. Y mejor aún, evitar el error comprobando el valor antes de convertirlo.

Answer (score 0):

Podrias definir un `factory` o `provider` que trabaje con el `$exceptionHandler`

[$exceptionHandler in AngularJS](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/cd7c2e/exceptionhandler-in-angularjs/)

http://jsfiddle.net/stever/pypdm/

```
x.factory('$exceptionHandler', function () {
        return function (exception, cause) {
            alert(exception.message);
        };
    });
```

de esta forma si lanzas un `throw`

```
x.controller('cont', function ($scope) {
        throw { message: 'error occurred' };
    });
```

el factory lo controlara de forma global