# Obtener todos los errores javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

¿Cómo hago para hacer un `catch` de todos los errores en la consola de javascript?
Estoy queriendo capturar todo error que se reproduce durante el ciclo del sitio y ejecutar una función cada vez que ocurra. Estoy utilizando **Angular 1.6**.

Encontré que con el `window.onerror` puedo obtener los errores pero no me captura los de **Angular**.

```
window.onerror = function (msg, url, lineNo, columnNo, error) {
  // ejecuto la función que quiero hacer
}
```

Comment: manejo de errores angular te dejo el link por si te ayuda, [angularjs error](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/4381/manejo-de-errores-en-angular)

Comment: Voy a probar eso, posiblemente me sirva.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Intenta sobreescribiendo el **provider** [`$exceptionHandler`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$exceptionHandler). Este captura todos los errores que angular produce.

Aquí un ejemplo:

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
  
})
.factory('logErrorsToBackend',function(){
  return function(exception, cause) {
    console.log('guardando error en la base de datos');
  }
})
.factory('$exceptionHandler', ['$log','logErrorsToBackend', function($log, logErrorsToBackend) {
    return function myExceptionHandler(exception, cause) {
      alert('ha ocurrido un error');
      logErrorsToBackend(exception, cause);
      $log.warn(exception, cause);
    }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

  {{asdfasf'}} <------- error de sintaxsis '

</div>
```

Comment: ¿Qué sería `logErrorsToBackend`?

Comment: @Kleith logErrorsToBackend es un servicio/factory de una dependencia que quieras definir. Actualize la respuesta ejemplificando un escenario donde guarda el error en el servido.

Answer (score -1):

Como se explica en este artículo de MDN, puede detectar errores de tiempo de ejecución de Javascript en un controlador de eventos window.onerror 
[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror)
***CODIGO:***

```
export class ErrorLogService {

    private errors = new Array<any>();

    constructor() {
        let that = this;
        window.onerror = function (msg, url, lineNo, columnNo, error) {
            let string = msg.toLowerCase();
            let substring = "script error";
            if (string.indexOf(substring) > -1) {
                console.log("Script Error: See Browser Console for Detail");
            } else {
                that.errors.push({
                    message: msg,
                    url: url,
                    line: lineNo,
                    column: columnNo,
                    error: error
                });
            }
            return false;
        };
        window.document.addEventListener("error", (event: ErrorEvent) => {
            if (event.target && (event.target as any).src) {
                let url = (event.target as any).src;
                this.errors.push({
                    message: "Resource not found",
                    url: url
                });
            } else {
                this.errors.push({
                    message: "Unknown error",
                    error: event
                });
            }
        }, true);
    }
}
```

ESPERO TE AYUDE !!

Comment: Eso fue lo que utilicé para probar pero no me agarra los errores de **Angular**. Además no me sirve que esté en ES6.

Comment: Respuesta reportada como baja calidad, la pregunta debe tratar de dar una solución al problema del OP. Te sugiero revises [answer].