# Manejo de errores en Angular con inject

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hace poco pregunté [cómo obtener los errores js](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/154546/obtener-todos-los-errores-javascript?noredirect=1#comment290012_154546) en Angular **1.6** pero ahora estoy teniendo un problema al intentar inyectar `$http` al `factory`. Me tira el siguiente error:

```
Circular dependency found: $rootScope <- $http <- $exceptionHandler <- $rootScope <- $route
```

Y esto fue lo que estuve realizando hasta ahora:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app
  .controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
    // controller
  })
  .factory('$exceptionHandler', ['$log', '$http', function($log, $http) {
    return function myExceptionHandler(exception, cause) {
      $log.warn(exception, cause);
      // muestro sólo esto y ya tira error
      console.log($http);
    }
  }]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

en vez de inyectar `$http` directamente dentro del interceptor, intento inyectar desde el `$injector` y usarlo directamente para obtener `$http`.

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.factory('$exceptionHandler', ['$log', '$injector', function($log, $injector) {
    return function myExceptionHandler(exception, cause) {
        var $http = $injector.get('$http');
        $log.warn(exception, cause);
        // muestro sólo esto y ya tira error
        console.log($http);
    }
}]);
```